# regex to recursively wrap with parentheses

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to wrap an expression with parentheses. The expression begins with some numbers math and ends with a unit, for example:

```
4+(5+6)*3 meter
(23+4)*3*(76+5) second
```

The result I want is:

```
(4+(5+6)*3) meter
((23+4)*3*(76+5)) second
```

The problem is that the function is called recursively and stops only if there was **no change** in the string after the `preg_replace`, so the following attempt:

```
preg_replace('/(.+)(?=\s+[a-z]+$)/', '($1)', '4+(5+6)*3 meter')
```

Will never stop and the results will be:

```
(4+(5+6)*3) meter
((4+(5+6)*3)) meter
(((4+(5+6)*3))) meter
etc..
```

I wonder if there is a way to make the replacement only if the math part is not already wrapped with parentheses. The second example of expression will make the solution a little harder.

Comment: `/^([^\(].+?[^\)])(?=\s+[a-z]+$)/`

Comment: @Deadooshka, your answer works, but you don't have to escape the  parenthesis inside the character class.

Comment: @Deadooshka it won't work for my second example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this after work and I think this will work. My idea here is to reduce the expression repetitively by removing the closet matching parenthesis until there is no more remaining. If the final expression is non-empty then we need to wrap the original expression with parenthesis otherwise we don't.

For example if the expression is `((1+2)*(2+1))+1` then reduction goes like this:

1. ((1+2)*(2+1))+1
2. (*)+1
3. +1

Here the final value is non-empty so we warp the expression: `(((1+2)*(2+1))+1)`.

Below is the code:

```
$input = $output = '(23+4)*3*(76+5) meter';
// Split into arithmetic expression and the unit string bit
if (preg_match('/^(.+?)\s*([a-z]+)$/', $input, $match)) {
    $exp = $match[1];
    $unit = $match[2];

    // This is the main logic
    // Reduce the expression by repetitively removing closet matching parenthesis 
    $reduced_exp = $exp;
    do {
        // The fifth parameter $count returns the number replacements done
        $reduced_exp = preg_replace('/\([^()]+\)/', '', $reduced_exp, -1, $count);
    } while ($count); // Exit the loop if there are zero replacements

    // If reduced expression is non-empty then we need to wrap it with the parenthesis
    if (!empty($reduced_exp)) {
        $output = '('.$exp.') '.$unit;
    }
}
print_r($output); // Outputs ((23+4)*3*(76+5))
```

Comment: Nice! I've tried some expressions and they all worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your first capture group adds the constraint that it's not within parenthesis:

```
preg_replace('/^([^(].+?[^)])(?=\s+[a-z]+$)/', '($1)', '4+(5+6)*3 meter')
```

**EDIT:**

As mentioned by @Talvir, this won't work in cases such as:

```
(1+2)*(3+4)
```

Since this means we need to keep track of the open and closes parenthesis with a stack machine (and something Regular Expressions aren't capable of), I don't think there is a solution with Regular Expressions.

Comment: This will not work for expression like `(1+2)*(3+4)`.